# Git Permission denied para pathnames mais extensos

Tags: oracle, git

Tenho que fazer o `clone` do projeto no diretório:

```
C:\xampp_5.3\htdocs\Meu-projeto
```

Executando primeiro a configuração para permitir `pathnames` mais extensos:

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Ao executar o comando acima, retorna este erro:

> error: could not lock config file C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Willian, isso não acontece pelo fato do caminho estar sendo passado metade com contra barra e metade com barra? Tente normalizar o seu caminho

Comment: certo funcionou, obrigado.

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta, para que as outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo possam consultar.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o motivo do erro são as barras do seu caminho, como elas estão metade barras e metades contra barras o erro acontece. Tente normalizar as barras de forma que todas fiquem da mesma maneira.